# After changing a links Inertial values dynamically, its behavior does not change

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am using Gazebo 1.8.0. In a plugin I am changing the Inertial values of some links, even though the values change, their behavior stays the same in the simulation.
Do I have to re-load them somehow?

Here is the code snippet how I set the values:

```
this->link->GetInertial()->SetInertiaMatrix(new_inertia, new_inertia, new_inertia, 0, 0, 0);
```

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2836/after-changing-a-links-inertial-values-dynamically,-its-behavior-does-not-change./) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After calling Link::SetInertiaMatrix, you'll need to call Link::UpdateMass. This is implemented for ODE, but not yet for bullet.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3